# Binary strings with exactly $n$ ones but without 000 or 111

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, combinatorics-on-words

I am a newbie in binary strings and generating series. I have a problem of enumeration which can be transformed to the following: find the number of binary strings of exactly $n$ ones which do not contain three consecutive ones or three consecutive zeros. The answer can be given as a coefficient of a generating series.

I don't know how to begin with. Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you convert each binary string to a sequence of $\{0,1,2\}$, where each element counts how many zeroes there are between two neighboring ones, you're looking for sequences of length $n+1$ that don't contain $00$ except possibly at the beginning or end. You can count those with standard recurrence techniques.

Comment: Define $b_1, b_2, b_3$ such that $b_i$ is the number of strings with exactly $n$ ones, whose last $i$ characters (but not the last $i + 1$ characters) are 1s, and which don't contain any 000 or 111. Define $c_1, c_2, c_3$ such that $c_i$ is the number of strings with exactly $n$ ones, whose last $i$ characters (but not the last $i + 1$ characters) are 0s, and which don't contain any 000 or 111. Find recurrence relations

Comment: (You actually only need $b_1(n)$ and $b_2(n)$ in @MarkSaving's scheme -- $b_3(n)=0$ by definition, and the $c$s can be folded into the recurrence for the $b$s. (This is relevant because having only two variables for each $n$ guarantees that you can use the quadratic formula to find the eigenvalues of the recurrence exactly, and derive an analogue of Binet's formula)).

Answer (score 4):

The following approach may be an overkill, but it's systematic and can easily get answer to many other similar problems.

Consider the [de Bruijn graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_graph) on $4$ vertices representing elements of $\{0,1\}^2$ (ie., $00$, $01$, $10$, and $11$), where edges represent elements of $\{0,1\}^3$. Remove edges corresponding to $000$ and $111$, and assign an algebraic weight $x$ to any edge leading to vertex $*1$, and weight $x^0=1$ to any edge leading to $*0$, and call the resulting graph $G$. Let $A$ be the (weighted) adjacency matrix of $G$ (with the same order of rows/columns as in the list of vertices above), that is

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
0 & x & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & x \\
1 & x & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Any binary string of length $\ell\geq 2$ without $000$ and $111$ represents a walk of length $\ell-2$ in $G$, and the power of $x$ in the weight of such a walk accounts for number of ones. More precisely, the number of binary strings of length $\ell\geq 2$ with exactly $n$ ones but without $000$ and $111$ is given by the coefficient $x^n$ in
$$[1,x,x,x^2]\cdot A^{\ell-2}\cdot [1,1,1,1]^T.$$
Summing over all $\ell\geq 2$, we get
$$[1,x,x,x^2]\cdot (I-A)^{-1}\cdot [1,1,1,1]^T = \frac{1 + 6x + 9x^2 + 2x^3}{1 - 2x - 2x^2}.$$
It remains to add the terms corresponding to $\ell=0$ and $\ell=1$ to get the generating function:
$$\frac{1 + 6x + 9x^2 + 2x^3}{1 - 2x - 2x^2} + 1 + (1+x) = 3\frac{1 + x + x^2}{1 - 2x - 2x^2}.$$

For more details on this approach, see *Section 4.7 The Transfer-matrix Method* in Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics* book. Also, in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.07926) a similar approach is applied to a generalization of Menage Problem.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

For these kinds of problems, I like to start with the part of the language that can be repeated and worry about fixing the ends of the strings afterwards. Here, the repeating part of the language is $(\{0,00\}\{1,11\})^*$. I.e. you can have one or two $0$s followed by one or two $1$s and just repeat that over and over again.

However, such strings will always start with a $0$ and end with a $1$ whereas we need to allow them to start with a $1$ or end with a $0$ as well. Therefore, at the beginning, we allow also $\{\epsilon, 1, 11\}$ and at the end, $\{\epsilon, 0, 00\}$. That finally gives

$$\{\epsilon, 1, 11\}(\{0,00\}\{1,11\})^*\{\epsilon, 0, 00\}.$$

This gives the generating function

$$ (1 + x + x^2) \frac{1}{1 - (1 + 1)(x + x^2)} (1 + 1 + 1).$$

We can simplify this to

$$\frac{3(1 + x + x^2)}{1 - 2x - 2x^2}.$$

Comment: This result doesn't seem to match a hand count for small $n$. I get 9 strings for $n=1$, namely $\{\varepsilon,0,00\}1\{\varepsilon,0,00\}$ and $27$ strings for $n=2$, namely $\{\varepsilon,0,00\}1\{\varepsilon,0,00\}1\{\varepsilon,0,00\}$. For $n=3$ there should be $81-9=72$ strings, namely $\bullet1{\bullet}1{\bullet}1\bullet$ with three possibilities for each $\bullet$ except $\bullet111\bullet$ is not allowed. And $9,27,72,\ldots$ does not look at all like the Fibonacci numbers times 2 ...

Comment: @Troposphere Thank you. I computed it at first with the weight being the length and it matched http://oeis.org/A128588 $2F_{n+1}$. My mistake was that if $w(0) = 0$ then the generating function of $\{\epsilon, 0, 00\}$ is $1 + 1 + 1$ not just "$1$." Likewise with the generating function of $\{0,00\}$.

Comment: The revised answer [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+expansion+9*%281%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%29%2F%281-2x-2x%5E2%29) $(9,27,81,216,\ldots)$ whereas my ad-hoc small-case counts want it to be $(9,27,72,198,\ldots)$.

Comment: @Troposphere You put in 9(1 + x + x^2) not 3(1 + x + x^2)

Comment: Ah, whoops. Then it actually matches my counts, it just confused me that it had an $n=0$ entry. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @TrevorGunn Just to be sure, the weight function $\omega$ you used here is not given by the length, right? Since you said $\omega(0)=0$, so I understand that here $\omega$ is given by the number of ones in the set, not the size of the set.

Comment: @mapping That's right. The two variable weight function (so marking $0$s by powers of $y$ and $1$s by powers of $x$) would be $$(1 + x + x^2)(1 + y + y^2) \frac{1}{1 - (x + x^2)(y + y^2)}$$. To weight by length, you can set $y = x$. To weight by number of $1$s you can set $y = 1$. I.e. $x^1$ or $x^0$.